# Implement a HtmlHelper extension that uses the routing system

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I'm trying to implement my own extension for HtmlHelper that will output a link in a similar fashion to ActionLink.

I know I can do this easily with TagBuilder for instance, but I'd like to take advantage of the routing system ability to construct outgoing urls as described by Scott Guthrie in [this vintage article](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing).

My application is centered around organizations. One user may create an organization and an organization may have multiple locations. The main action takes place within a current location. I consider an organization to be a tenant in my application and the organization id is sent via the url.

Here's the route configuration for the above:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Tenant",
    url: "Tenants/{tenantId}/{action}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Organizations",
        action = "Dashboard",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "TenantLocation",
    url: "Tenants/{tenantId}/Locations/{locationId}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Dashboard",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

For route "Tenant", the controller is always Organizations. This part of the application takes care of administrative actions regarding an organization as a whole. The context here contains a tenant id.

For route "TenantLocation", the context shifts inside a location, so the context contains a tenant id and a location id.

Now, I'd like to create two extension methods for HtmlHelper called TenantActionLink and TenantLocationActionLink to generate such links as:

```
/Tenants/150/Dashboard
```

or

```
/Tenants/150/Locations/300/Team/Edit/1000
```

The part "/Tenants/150/Locations/300/" could be considered as a prefix to be prepended to a URL, the ids being extracted by an ActionFilterAttribute and stored as properties in a BaseController class.

As I mentioned, I could generate the links easily with TagBuilder, but if I change the routes later, I have to update all the calls of the tenant action links methods in all the views and controllers.

Any advice on how to tackle this? 
I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and .NET Framework 4.6.1

Thanks.

---

Update to answer Stephen Muecke's [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220688/implement-a-htmlhelper-extension-that-uses-the-routing-system#comment91389994_52220688):

> What have you tried so far?

I implemented the extensions like this (for simplicity I'm including only the code for TenantLocationActionLink, the other one is similar):

```
public static MvcHtmlString TenantLocationActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
    int tenandId,
    int locationId,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    var url = $"/Tenants/{tenandId}/Locations/{locationId}/{controllerName}/{actionName}";

    var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");
    tagBuilder.InnerHtml = linkText;
    tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
    tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

    return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

> and what problems are you having?

I can't figure out how to handle the routeValues. My implementation is somehow a stepdown from the more flexible implementation of ActionLink, especially since it doesn't take into account routeValues.
How am I going to handle the situations when my route configuration will get more complex?

> And what are you expecting your extension method to do that the
>   inbuilt ActionLink() or RouteLink() don't?

Prepend the tenant and location ids as described above. How could I use ActionLink() or RouteLink() to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems are you having? And what are you expecting your extension method to do that the inbuilt `ActionLink()` or `RouteLink()` don't?

Comment: I updated the question with my answers. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest your start by studying the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/LinkExtensions.cs). but you can simply use `@Html.RouteLink("linkText", "TenantLocation", new { tenantId = x, locationId = y, controller = "..." etc })` Its still not clear what you expect your method to do that the inbuilt helpers do not since the inbuilt helpers will generate the correct url and html

Comment: To be honest, I haven't look well enough into RouteLink and your comment pretty much answers my question. Please add it as an answer so I can mark it accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a `RouteLink()` extension method that you can use for this. You pass it the link text and the name of the route definition, and an object (or a `RouteValueDictionary`) for the parameters and it will generate the correct `href` attribute. In your case, for the `Tenant` route

```
@Html.RouteLink("...", "Tenant", new { tenantId = 150, action = "Dashboard" })
```

generates `.../Tenants/150/Dashboard`,

and for the `TenantLocation`

```
@Html.RouteLink("...", "TenantLocation", new { tenantId = 150, locationId = 300, controller = "Team", action = "Edit", id = 1000 })
```

generates `../Tenants/150/Locations/300/Team/Edit/1000`

Comment: Also, if one needs to add elements inside the <a> tag, use @Url.RouteUrl() in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Paul. There is also an overload of `RouteLink()` that allows you to add html attributes - e.g. `@Html.RouteLink("...", "Tenant", new { tenantId = 150, action = "Dashboard" }, new { @class = "..." })`

Comment: Yep, I know that one, I was referring to other elements inside the <a> tag, like an <img> for instance. AFAIK, this cannot be done by inserting the element html code in the linkText parameter of RouteLink, as it gets encoded.

Comment: Yes that's correct - in that case you need to use `< a href=@Url.RouteLink(..)`